# How can I change the URL to the Django admin interface?

Tags: python, django, security, url, admin

For an extra little bit of security I want to change the default django admin url to the custom one, e.g. change mysite.com/admin/ to mysite.com/mysecretadmin/ so that admin is completely unaccessible via default url.

I tried some solutions from the internet, for example I changed urls.py like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('api.views',
    ...,
    ...,
    url(r'^secret-admin-url/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Nothing worked for me, sadly. Does anyone know the solution? I use django 1.5.4.

Comment: That's the correct solution. You can try to put it on top of your list for debugging purposes.

Comment: It turns out that I was using wrong urls.py file. My app has two - one main urls.py and one app-specific urls.py in app directory. You have to change main urls.py file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Refer to the section 'Hooking AdminSite instances into your URLconf' in the url
below
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#hooking-adminsite-to-urlconf

Comment: The above link seems to be broken now

Comment: @PrakharAgrawal if you are using newer version of django, try changing url of admin `url(r'^<custom-url>/', admin.site.urls),`. This is working without any issues with recent versions of django.

Comment: That was giving errors after every few requests for some unknown reason, in the beginning, still unknown to me. And the error said that ^admin$ was still a valid url. Over the time it became more stable and it works now. I am very confused to as why that happened, and so I thought I might need to change somewhere else.

Comment: to add security change `admin/` to something like `admin_NAtEsoNsibingSTilEBOl`. When you use `href="{% url 'admin:index'` this will then reference to this link...

Answer (score 5):

For those who find this question in recent times. Based on the [Django 3.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#hooking-adminsite-to-urlconf) docs:

register the default **AdminSite** instance **django.contrib.admin.site** at the URL **/admin/**:

```
# main project urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
]
```

you can simply change the `admin/` url to anything you wish:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("my_custom_url/", admin.site.urls),
]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you do not want to use the default page `/admin` you can add a secret key to admin. So in `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin_eTiOmEthelInEwathbace/', admin.site.urls,),
]
```

If in your template you have a link

```
<a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Admin</a>
```

then this will reference to the above site with url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin_eTiOmEthelInEwathbace/`

Now you do not want to publish this `secret_key`, therefore get it from an environment variable with for example `decouple`, so `urls.py` then becomes

```
from decouple import config
SECRET_ADMIN = config('SECRET_ADMIN')

urlpatterns = [
    path(f'admin_{SECRET_ADMIN}/', admin.site.urls,),
]
```

Answer (score 2):

**If you want to prevent brute force or dictionary attack and your admin login page not accessible for unauthorized user,normal user. please follow this step:**

**First install django admin honeypot and signal**

```
pip install django-admin-honeypot(inastall in settings.py)
pip install django-honeypot-signals(inastall in settings.py)
```

**override this .txt file(because **future** tag is deprecated):**

**templates/honeypot_signals/notification.txt:**

```
{% load i18n %}
{% blocktrans with site_name=site.name %}
{% endblocktrans %}

Invalid login attempt from your duplicate ADMIN panel..
• Review entry at http://{{ site.domain }}{% url "admin:admin_honeypot_loginattempt_change" object.id %} 

Username: {{ object.username }}
IP: {{ object.ip_address }}
Timestamp: {{ object.timestamp }}
```

django-admin-honeypot make a fake admin login page and django honeypot signal send email to admin with credentials if any person try to access your fake admin login page.

How to access main admin login page?:

- `pip install django-decorator-include`

**Your main urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls.conf import include
from . import settings
from decorator_include import decorator_include
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, user_passes_test
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from django.core.mail.message import EmailMessage
from datetime import datetime
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

def only_user():
    def check(user):
        if user.is_authenticated and user.is_superuser or user.is_staff:
            return True
        
        time = datetime.now()
        message = f'----------------------------------\nName: {user.username}\nEmail: {user.email}\nTime: {time}.\n----------------------------------\n • {user.username} is not a staff user or admin.For some security reasons..Please block this user from your admin panel(Blacklist).'
        
        email = EmailMessage(
                            f'Alert!! {user.username} is try to accessing your admin panel!!', 
                            message,
                            settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                            [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER], 
                            )
        email.fail_silently = False
        email.send()
        
        raise PermissionDenied
    return user_passes_test(check)

urlpatterns = [  
                 
    path('', include('product.urls')),
    
    #This is all fake admin urls...
    path('admin/', include('admin_honeypot.urls', 
          namespace='admin_honeypot')),
    path('site/admin/',RedirectView.as_view(url='/admin')),
    path('user/admin/',RedirectView.as_view(url='/admin')),
    path('secure/admin/',RedirectView.as_view(url='/admin')),
    path('mysite/admin/',RedirectView.as_view(url='/admin')),
    path('admin/secure',RedirectView.as_view(url='/admin')),
    path('real/admin/',RedirectView.as_view(url='/admin')),
    
    #This is real admin login page url
    path('custom_url/', 
         decorator_include([login_required, only_user()], 
         admin.site.urls)),

]
```

For this way you can not access directly your admin login page.. first you need to login your website and then accessible your admin panel..

**How to protect website's login page from the attackers?:**

```
 - Use django defender (https://django-defender.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
 ---------------------OR-------------------------
 - Use google hidden(ReCaptchaV2Invisible) recaptcha field 
 (https://pypi.org/project/django-recaptcha/)
```

If any unauthorized users terrible activity detected.You block their IP address or username by using this django package:

```
pip install django-blacklist
```

Read docs : [django-blacklist](https://pypi.org/project/django-blacklist/#:%7E:text=Django%20Blacklist%20allows%20you%20to,applied%20for%20a%20specific%20duration.)

•sorry for my English